# Get BaseName Of Element DTE _applicationObject Visual Studio Add-In

Tags: .net, visual-studio, add-in

I'm trying to get definition of element with visual studio add-in but I can't reach
the signature of the element on selected line.

I have a code blocks like:

```
sub Test(){
  Dim TestVariable As New TestClass
  TestVariable.Execute()
}
```

I select the line that is

```
TestVariable.Execute()
```

But this operation, which is in add-in:

```
_applicationObject.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel. _
CodeElementFromPoint(sel.AnchorPoint, vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction)
```

returns me Test(), which is topmost element, but i need the innermost.

I tried to change 'vsCMElementFunction' property to attribute etc.
but they all returned Nothing.

Does anyone know another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem, and I wanted to share it.

```
'When Your Cursor On The Element, Call Your Add-In
'In Exec() Function You Can Follow These Steps:

'Open Object Browser And Copy The Signature

_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToDefinition")
_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Copy")

'To Close The Object Browser

Dim win As EnvDTE.Window
win = DirectCast(_applicationObject.ActiveWindow, EnvDTE.Window)

'And ta ta, Full Signature Of The Element

basename = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()

'And Here We Get The Base Name

Dim tobjbasearr As String() = basename.Split(CChar("."))
Dim tobjbase As String = tobjbasearr(0)
```